# CSS Multiple Media Query - one rule works, the other doesn't

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a webpage with a CSS stylesheet linked to it. I am trying to insert various media query rules, but the first rule is applied, and the second (and third, fourth...) don't.

This style applies:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
.submenu {
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 3fr 1fr 1fr;
}
}
```

This style DOES NOT apply:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
.submenu img {
width: 250px;
height: 180px;
}
}
```

I have already:

1. Inserted the code below in my head:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

2. Tried to separate CSS files for media query only.
3. Tried to put both rules under the same selector (since the selectors are absolutely the same!), like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
    .submenu {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 3fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
    .submenu img {
        width: 250px;
        height: 180px;
    }
}
```

I am using Edge.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Images are inline elements, which means they can't be sized unless you give them a `display: block` or give their parent a set width and/or height and give the image a width/height of any %

Comment: May you give the full code, HTML specifically? thanks

Comment: @auTiStiCWizArD what you are saying is true for _actual_ inline elements, but not for _replaced_ inline elements such as images.

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the elements? Does the rule apply? Do the properties in question get overwritten by a _different_ rule?

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for your feedback. The rule was indeed being overwritten by another rule that was more "important" (because of the type of selector). I managed to correct it by adding the !important ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `.submenu img`, the rule is probably overwritten by another css rule. Use dev tools to inspect elements and in `Computed` properties, search for `width` or `height` of the image, and you would probably see multiple styles applied for it and the last one is likely the applicable one. You can also type on the style to see where it is defined. 
One work around is to mark the media query rule as `!important` like the following. If that doesn't work, please share your html and css to inspect the problem.

```
@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
    .submenu {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 3fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
    .submenu img {
        width: 250px!important;
        height: 180px!important;
    }
}
```